# How to use MySQLFullPrunedBlockStore with bitcoinj-core-0.13-bundled.jar

Tags: blockchain, bitcoinj

Initailly i am using bitcoinj-core-0.12.2.jar and bitcoinj-tools-0.12.2.jar on my project.Now i updated it with bitcoinj-core-0.13-bundled.jar because i am assuming that bitcoinj-core-0.13-bundled is providing support for MySQLFullPrunedBlockStore.

I have created a new database in mysql with bitcoinj when i run-app my grails app it create following tables

**headers

openoutputs

settings

undoableblocks**

and show following error
**| Error org.bitcoinj.store.BlockStoreException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'bitcoinj.undoableBlocks' doesn't exist**

To remove this error i have renamed table undoableblocks with undoableBlocks.

and i again run-app my app and it show following error
**| Error org.bitcoinj.store.BlockStoreException: Database block store is not compatible with the current release.  See bitcoinj release notes for further information: Table 'bitcoinj.openOutputs' doesn't exist**

To remove this error i have renamed table openoutputs with openOutputs.

and i again run-app my app and it show following error
**| Error org.bitcoinj.store.BlockStoreException: corrupt database block store - no chain head pointer ...**

Can anybody tell me how to slove this error.